# Verificar números randômicos (randint)

Tags: python

Comecei a aprender python essa semana e tava fazendo umas perguntas e em uma tem varias respostas diferentes mais quando as digito me retorna sempre a mesma coisa como se as outras não existisse

Este e o código:

```
from random import*
espaco = " "
Question_4 = "Eu estou pensando em um numero de 1 a 99. \nConsegue adivinhar ?"
Valor_maior = "Menos que isso"
Valor_menor = "Mais que isso"
def pergunta4():
     number = randint(1,99)
     print espaco
     print Question_4
     print espaco
     resposta = raw_input ()
     if resposta == resposta > number:
          print espaco
          print Valor_menor
          print espaco
          print pergunta4()
     elif resposta == resposta < number:
          print espaco
          print Valor_maior
          print espaco
          print pergunta4()
     elif resposta == number:
          print espaco
          print "E isso ae"
          print espaco 
          print replay()
     elif resposta == "desisto":
          print espaco
          print "ohh que pena o resultado era "
          print number
          print espaco
          print replay()
def replay():
     print espaco
     print "Deseja brincar novamente ? (s/n)"
     print espaco
     decisao = raw_input ()
     if decisao == "s":
          print pergunta4()
     if decisao == "n":
          print "ok"

pergunta4()
```

executo pra ver se esta bom mais qualquer coisa que digito me retorna a mesma coisa poderiam me ajudar ?

a ideia principal era que ele gerasse qualquer numero entre 1 a 99 e se eu disse-se um numero maior doque ele fez ele me responderia que o numero e menor e se eu falasse um numero menor ele diria  que era maior ate eu acertar mais o erro e basicamente isso

```
Eu estou pensando em um numero de 1 a 99. 
Consegue adivinhar ?

99999

Mais que isso
```

eu disse que o numero era 99999 e ele disse que era mais que isso mais o limite era de 99 :( e nao importa o valor sempre aparece isso 
 sim modifiquei o codigo pra ajudar a ler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que está acontecendo é que você está perguntando se uma string é maior ou menor que um número.

```
>>> rinfo = raw_input()
8
>>> type(rinfo)
<type 'str'>
```

Como pode ver a entrada retorna uma string, e a comparação acaba sendo feita como essa:

```
>>> rinfo = '1'
>>> rinfo > 20
True
```

Se você não definir que se trata de um número inteiro ou float, ele não irá realizar a comparação de forma correta.

O certo seria transformar a entrada que é do tipo string para inteiro:

```
>>> rinfo = int(raw_input())
8
>>> type(rinfo)
<type 'int'>
>>> rinfo > 3
True
```

Além disso, no código não há necessidade de comparar a mesma variável, isso:

```
if rinfo == rinfo>rn:
    pass
```

Deveria ser isso:

```
if rinfo > rn:
    pass
```

Bom, refiz aqui o algoritmo pois o seu estava sempre sorteando novamente o número quando o usuário realizava uma nova tentativa. O seu código poderia ficar dessa maneira:

```
from random import *

def iniciar_jogo():

    numero_sorteado = randint(1, 99)
    print numero_sorteado, type(numero_sorteado)

    def pergunta():
        entrada = raw_input('Eu estou pensando em um numero de 1 a 99. \nConsegue adivinhar? ')
        if int(entrada) > numero_sorteado:
            print 'Menos do que isso'
            pergunta()
        elif int(entrada) < numero_sorteado:
            print "Mais do que isso"
            pergunta()
        else:
            print "Acertou! O numero era %i" % numero_sorteado
            decisao = raw_input('Deseja jogar novamente?')
            if decisao == 's':
                iniciar_jogo()
            else:
                print 'fim'

    # faz a primeira pergunta
    pergunta()

iniciar_jogo()
```

Com a opção "desisto" incluída:

```
from random import *

def iniciar_jogo():

    numero_sorteado = randint(1, 99)
    print numero_sorteado, type(numero_sorteado)

    def pergunta():
        entrada = raw_input('Eu estou pensando em um numero de 1 a 99. \nConsegue adivinhar? ')
        try:
            entrada = int(entrada)
        except ValueError:
            # se for do tipo string a entrada:
            if entrada == 'desisto':
                print "O numero era %i" % numero_sorteado
                jogar_novamente()
            else:
                print "Digite um numero para adivinhar ou 'desisto' para sair"
                pergunta()
        else:
            # se for do tipo inteiro:
            if entrada > numero_sorteado:
                print 'Menos do que isso'
                pergunta()
            elif entrada < numero_sorteado:
                print "Mais do que isso"
                pergunta()
            else:
                print "Acertou! O numero era %i" % numero_sorteado
                jogar_novamente()

    def jogar_novamente():
        decisao = raw_input('Deseja jogar novamente?')
        if decisao == 's':
            iniciar_jogo()
        else:
            print 'fim'

    pergunta()

iniciar_jogo()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado caio ate umas lagrimas >< vou tentar obrigado muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: agora ta dando isso

    Eu estou pensando em um numero de 1 a 99. 
    Consegue adivinhar ?
 
    63
 
    Menos que isso
Eu estou pensando em um numero de 1 a 99. 
     Consegue adivinhar ?
 
    63
 
Mais que isso
 
 
Eu estou pensando em um numero de 1 a 99. 
Consegue adivinhar ?

Comment: como o mesmo valor pode dar 2 resposta diferente ?

Comment: @Fagner se a entrada for tanto número quanto texto, você pode utilizar `rinfo = raw_input()` e na hora da comparação tratar o tipo. ex(`if int(rinfo) > rn`).

Comment: orion ele continua dando dois resultados pra o mesmo valor oq faço ?

Comment: @Fagner, seu algoritmo toda hora faz uma nova tentativa ele sorteia um novo número. Vou por um exemplo na minha resposta.

Comment: @Fagner refiz o algoritmo, veja como ficou.

Comment: Muito obrigado. espero nao ter incomodado, cara... s2

Comment: @Fagner unica coisa que está faltando é a opção "desisto", vou incluir

Comment: @Fagner adicionei a opção de 'desistir'. Utilizando exceção o código tenta converter a entrada para inteiro, caso ocorra um erro, é verificado se o usuário quis desistir, caso tenha sido um número, é realizado a verificação.

Comment: Quando você diz que  "não há necessidade de comparar a mesma variável", dá a impressão que o `if rinfo == rinfo>rn` funcionaria. É isso mesmo? Acho que não, né? Mesmo se a precedência do `==` fosse maior (acho que não é), o lado esquerdo acabaria dando true, estragando a comparação com o `>`.

Comment: @bfavaretto em Python é possível fazer esse tipo de comparação, nesse caso `(3 == 3 > 2)` retornaria `True`, e `(3 == 3 > 5)` retornaria `False`, é o mesmo que `True if 3 > 2 > 1 else False`.

Comment: Por favor, note que "O certo seria informar que se trata de um inteiro" é uma afirmação incorreta. `int(x)` gera um novo inteiro a partir do objeto "x" O que está snedo feita ai é uma criação de um inteito a partir de uma string - pode até se pensar nisso como uma "conversão" - mas não "informar que se trata de".

Comment: @jsbueno correto, o que se faz é a transformação de uma `string` para um `integer`.

Comment: Testei e realmente funciona. Só que ainda não entendi muito bem como, vou estudar mais python. Ou quem sabe postar uma pergunta sobre o assunto aqui no site :)

Comment: Postei uma pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68249/como-o-python-interpreta-v%C3%A1rios-operadores-de-compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-sequ%C3%AAncia