# Como o Python interpreta vários operadores de comparação em sequência?

Tags: python

Constatei o seguinte usando um REPL de Python:

```
3 == 3 > 2
=> True
```

Inicialmente pensei que poderia ser algo relacionado à precedência dos operadores, porém:

```
3 == (3 > 2)
=> False
(3 == 3) > 2
=> False
```

Como isso funciona então? Ele está retornando simplesmente o resultado de `3 == 3` e ignorando a parte do `> 2`? Ou será que ele faz `3 == 3 AND 3 > 2`? Ou alguma outra coisa? Sei muito pouco de Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De fato, sua última interpretação está correta. Uma expressão idiomática comum na programação é testar se um número pertence a um intervalo, i.e. se ele é maior (ou igual) a `a` e menor (ou igual) a `b`. Em C por exemplo, faríamos assim:

```c
if ( a < x && x < b) {
```

Enquanto na matemática escrevemos simplesmente:

```
a < x < b
```

Python resolveu dar suporte a essa segunda forma, interpretando algo escrito como:

```python
if a < x < b:
```

Como:

```
if a < x and x < b:
```

Por essa razão, três ou mais operadores de comparação em sequência são mesmo interpretados como pares unidos com "E". De modo que é equivalente escrever:

```
if 3 == 3 > 2:
```

E:

```
if 3 == 3 and 3 > 2:
```

Resultando, como você percebeu, em `True`.

Nota: equivalente *desde que os operandos não tenham efeitos colaterais*; `a() == b() > c()` só avalia as funções uma única vez, enquanto `a() == b() and b() > c()` avaliaria `b` duas vezes.

Comment: Ah! Se eu tivesse esbarrado com um exemplo como `a < x < b`, talvez a dúvida não aparecesse. Com o `==` fica um pouco mais obscuro.